# How does the behavior of a child component using `react-redux` change when its parent rerenders?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

At [react-redux's hooks documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#performance) we are warned that `useSelector` "does not prevent the component from re-rendering due to its parent re-rendering, even if the component's props did not change," unlike `connect`

This is news to me. Does `connect` prevent re-rendering where a normal child component would not re-render? More specifically, I'm asking about the difference in the re-rendering behavior of the below three scenarios when the parent component re-renders while the store and props remain unchanged:

1. The child component is wrapped in a `connect` HOC.
2. Behavior as 1., but injected state is refactored into `useSelector`.
3. As 2., but `useSelector` and everything dependent on it is removed.

Comment: Did you try making examples and check it?

Comment: @DennisVash I'm not very familiar with `connect`'s possible optimizations to React's re-render behavior. I wouldn't know if I can trust my results if I were to make my own examples or if I were missing/failing to distinguish an optimization scenario with them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`connect` has always acted like a more sophisticated version of React's `PureComponent`.  Specifically, when the parent of a connected component renders, `connect` will only re-render the child component if the new "merged props" have changed from before, where `const mergeProps = { ...ownProps, ...stateProps, ...dispatchProps }`.

So, if a parent component is passing down the same props as before, the `connect` wrapper will prevent the wrapped component from re-rendering.

With the hooks, there is no wrapper component preventing this component from re-rendering if its parent is passing down the same props.  You would need to wrap your component in `React.memo()` to achieve that.  And, in fact, that is exactly how `connect` itself is implemented in version 7.

(Source: I'm a Redux maintainer and wrote React-Redux v7.)